# Can I ask for programming feedback on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am learning to program in AS3 through online tutorials, the documentation reference, asking specific questions on StackOverflow, and writing code. I've noticed that I have a severe need for feedback on the programs I write. It's all good and well to just read and try to follow standards and good programming principles, but without someone to read my code and say "you're doing this wrong", I feel like I'll never be able to know if I'm doing well or not.

So the question is, is it appropriate to ask for feedback on StackOverflow?

If not, where would be a place that I could? Unfortunately I'm not in a situation where I could receive some kind of professional teaching from an educational institution, so I can only rely on help from online sources.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There’s a Stack Exchange site for that!

[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Congratulations! You have gained enough reputation to bounty.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even see that site in all site for stack exchange. Thanks :)